# Imageview floating left

Tags: android, layout, imageview

How can I create ImageView floating to the left of the textView, something like html:

```
<div>
<img src="src" style="float:left"> Text here.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- With LinearLayout, setting the orientation to horizontal so the image is first and then come the rest.
- With RelativeLayout, there you can indicate the position of a element relative to another with the attributes of the style android:layout_toLeftOft, android:layout_toRightOf, android:layout_below or android:layout_alignParentTop, ...

However, it is not so flexible as CSS for some actions and, for example, wrapping text around an image is not so easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no concept of floating elements in Android, but you can easily put an image to the left of some text using the [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft) attribute of the `TextView`. Example:

Otherwise, for more complicated layouts, parent views determine how their children are laid out.  For example, instead of the concept of a `div` which simply wraps it children and uses the `float` and `display` attributes of the children to determine how things look, Android has more complex parent views (`ViewGroup`s as they are called, since that's the super class) to control things.

Check out the docs for [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) and [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of views depend on the kind of layout you use. In case if you are using a RelativeLayout and you want to float your view(in your case the ImageView) which is within this Relativelayout, you can use the attribute of the ImageView (android:layout_toLeftOf="") specifying the view id of your textview between the double quote.